# Create a function for axios requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to created a global function for handle axios requests such `post` `get` `delete` `put` so I create a file called `requests.js` for example for `post` requests I created a function called `post()`

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const post = async (url, data, config) => {
    axios.post(url, data, config).then((result)=>{
        return result;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return error;
    });
}
```

So now I want everywhere want to call a `post` request use this function instead of direct axios post call, so for example in data.js:

```
import {post} from './requests'

export const postMembersData = (url, data) => {
    return post(url, data);
};

export const postCarsData = (url, data) => {
    return post(url, data);
};
```

I call `postMembersData`  function in index.js:

```
const postMembersDataApi = async() => {
        await postMembersData(url, data).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res); // handle data for view

        }).catch((error)=>{
         console.log(error); // handle errors for alert or etc
        });
    }
```

Everything looking good but there is a problem, when I get error such 500 or 400 or etc, it still return `res` not `error` in other hand it won't return error at all, Am I did something wrong?

Comment: you can try removing the `.catch` in `post` function, since the exception is handled there it would handle it when its called later

Comment: @Azzy I need that, because I want to handle `401` error for all post requests once.

Answer (score 0):

try to run axios in `return`

```js
export const post = async (url, data, config) => {
    return axios.post(url, data, config).then((result)=>{
        return result;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return error;
    });
}
```

You return the result and the error correctly but to `post` function scope, and this function return undefined.
you need to return what returned from axios to be returned from `post` function.

Comment: Still it won't return error to `postMembersData` for example

Comment: The `catch` in second function will be returned if the second function failed NOT THE FIRST. If the first return `res` or `err` Both will be in res. You can handle the second function to check if the param is res or err. Or In the first function in the `.catch` usse `throw error`. And the second will recive an error thrown. And will be handlen in the `.catch`.